# How can I add Bundle Config to Startup.cs for resources to use in Razor Views?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The question. How can I add to Startup.cs (ASP.NET Core project) same configuration as I was doing with App_Start > BundleConfig.cs

When having:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com
/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
```

and then:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

for example...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bundling and Minification as it existed in MVC5 no longer exists in MVC Core.

Your options are (without delving into the Node ecosystem - which is just as valid but would introduce more concepts):

- Use the [bundling and minification Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier).
- Or use the [command line bundling and minification dotnet tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier/).

Both of these tools operate on the same infrastructure under the covers. They use a `bundleConfig.json` file to describe the structure of your bundles (what files go in, what file comes out, wether to include sourcemaps, etc.)

Explanations of these two concepts are also available via the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification).

Instead of having a call to `@Scripts.Render()` which would produce links to either minified or unminified resources depending on your build environment, you can use `taghelpers` to swap between links to minified and unminified resources. For example:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/unminified.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/bundledandminified.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Answer (score 13):

I needed the run-time bundling features of System.Web.Optimization (to be able to do dynamic Less compilation ) so I implemented a NET Core replacement for that and now I've decided to [publish it](https://github.com/adams85/bundling) under MIT license.

If you want to use it, first you need to install an implementation NuGet package:

```
dotnet add package Karambolo.AspNetCore.Bundling.NUglify
```

or

```
dotnet add package Karambolo.AspNetCore.Bundling.WebMarkupMin
```

Whichever minifier library you prefer.

Then you need to register it in the DI container in Startup.ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddBundling()
    .UseDefaults(_env)
    .UseNUglify(); // or .WebMarkupMin(), respectively
```

The field _env is a reference to IHostingEnvironment, you can inject it in the constructor.

Now you can configure your bundles in the Configure() method as follows:

```
app.UseBundling(bundles =>
{
    bundles.AddJs("/jquery.js")
        .Include("/Scripts/jquery-*.js");

    bundles.AddJs("/jqueryval.js")
        .Include("/Scripts/jquery.validate*");

    // and so on...
});
```

Note the tildes and the "/bundles" prefix removed (since it's added automatically) and the extensions added to the bundle path. It's required to use the correct extension which corresponds to the output of the bundle.

Add the following to your _ViewImports.cshtml:

```
@using Karambolo.AspNetCore.Bundling.ViewHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Karambolo.AspNetCore.Bundling
```

In the Razor views you can use the familiar syntax:

```
@await Scripts.RenderAsync("~/bundles/jquery.js")
@await Scripts.RenderAsync("~/bundles/jqueryval.js")
```

or the new tag helper syntax:

```
<script src="~/bundles/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/bundles/jqueryval.js"></script>
```

Note that in the views you must add the tilde and the prefix. For more on this and other details please refer to the [project page](https://github.com/adams85/bundling).

Comment: This is not working at my project, I do not know why. I have following the guides, and still getting 404

Comment: Just tested the QuickStartTemplate sample application included in the repo on .NET 8 and it works as expected. So it's highly likely that something is wrong with your application's configuration. If not, please open an issue in the GitHub repo and submit an MRE.

Answer (score 0):

The [Core 5.0 docs note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-5.0#choose-a-bundling-and-minification-strategy) that [WebOptimizer is a compatible solution](https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer).

> ASP.NET Core is compatible with WebOptimizer, an open-source bundling and minification solution. For set up instructions and sample projects, see WebOptimizer. ASP.NET Core doesn't provide a native bundling and minification solution.
>
> Third-party tools, such as Gulp and Webpack, provide workflow automation for bundling and minification, as well as linting and image optimization. By using design-time bundling and minification, the minified files are created prior to the app's deployment. Bundling and minifying before deployment provides the advantage of reduced server load. However, it's important to recognize that design-time bundling and minification increases build complexity and only works with static files.